# Minor issues with worded function problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, optimization

Having some problems with these questions:

[image]

[image]

Q3b) What's the best way to find the domain? I was initially pretty lost but would considering $x - 12>0$ and $y-20>0$ be best? Also I'm not sure why the answer has the domain as exclusive $12$ but inclusive $60$. Shouldn't they both be exclusive?

Q4b) Why don't we need to state the domain of $V$? The answer only gave the domain of $x$.

Q6d) how do we determine the shape? Area = $6a/(a+2)$.

Thanks

Comment: It is a bit long for a single question. Maybe you should split it into 3 questions. Moreover, as this is clearly a homework, it is usually appreciated if you show your thoughts on the question. Finally, note that this question has not much to do with "principal-ideal-domains"...

Comment: "Also I'm not sure why the answer has the domain as exclusive 12 but inclusive 60. Shouldn't they both be exclusive?" No.  Because 0 < Area $\le$ 160.  The area must be greater than 0 which means x > 12.  And the area *can* be as large as 160 which means x *can* be as large as 60.

Comment: "but would considering x−12>0 and y−20>0 be best"  If the function input is $x$ and the function is terms of x only and not y, then you only need to find the possible values of x.  x -12 > 0 or x > 12 is part of it.  But you also must have x $\le$ 60.

Comment: To figure out the appropriate domain in 3b) you must first do 3a) and find the formula for the area.  I will not do that for you.  But if you tell me what you have I will explain how to find the domain.

Comment: "Why don't we need to state the domain of V? The answer only gave the domain of x."  V is a fixed constant.  It isn't a variable and it isn't input.

Comment: 6d)  The rectangle is just the points O = (0,0).  B = (0, f(a)), C = (a, f(a)), D = (a, 0).  So the area is $a\times f(a) $.

Comment: Thanks fleablood. For 6d, I found the equation but I'm unsure on how to determine its shape?